# How Do I Mesh a Numeric Vector and a Character Matrix?

Tags: r, object, matrix, vector, knitr

I'm new to R, and trying to work a side project to supplement my in-class learning.

I'm trying to match something like this vector

````
```{R}
matrixvalues <- sample(8, 8 , replace=TRUE)
```
````

Which in this example results in

```
8 3 4 2 4 5 5 1
```

to this matrix

```
#     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,] "C"  "S"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
#[2,] "C"  "S"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
#[3,] "C"  "S"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M" 
#[4,] "C"  "S"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "M"  "M" 
#[5,] "C"  "S"  "H"  "H"  "H"  "M"  "M"  "M" 
#[6,] "C"  "S"  "H"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "M" 
#[7,] "C"  "S"  "H"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "M" 
#[8,] "C"  "S"  "H"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "M"  "M"
```

where for each value in the vector, it sequentially matches in the matrix column.

So for this, the output vector would logically work like...

```
Vector value 1 is 8, so row 1, column 8 is M...

Vector value 2 is 3, so row 2, column 3 is H...
```

and so on...

so the resulting vector is

```
M , H , H , S , H , M , M , C
```

---

Here's the working code, I'll update it as I go...

## Create Offense Matrix

```
example <- c("C","S","H","H","H","H","H","M","C","S","H","H","H","H","H","M","C","S","H","H","H","H","H","M","C","S","H","H","H","M","M","M","C","S","H","H","H","M","M","M","C","S","H","M","M","M","M","M","C","S","H","M","M","M","M","M","C","S","H","M","M","M","M","M")
rollmatrix <- matrix (example, 8 , 8 , byrow = TRUE)
rollmatrix
```

## Roll Dice

```
set.seed(1234) 
matrixvalues <- sample( 8 , 8 , replace=TRUE)
matrixvalues
```

## Evaluate Initial Roll

```
inx_mat <- cbind(row = seq_along(matrixvalues), col = matrixvalues)
initialroll <- rollmatrix[inx_mat]
initialroll
```

Comment: Try to keep questions specific and focused. If you have two distinct questions, you should split them into two separate posts

Comment: The second question is solved with an index matrix: `inx_mat <- cbind(row = seq_along(matrixvalues), col = matrixvalues)` Then use this `inx_mat` to get the values you want, `matrixchar[inx_mat]`.

Comment: @camille is that better? I'll resubmit the other question once the question cooldown expires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an index matrix, in this case a matrix with 2 columns, the rows and columns.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the code reproducible

x <- matrix(sample(LETTERS, 64, replace = TRUE), 8)
matrixvalues <- sample(8, 8, replace = TRUE)
```

Now for the index matrix.

```
inx_mat <- cbind(row = seq_along(matrixvalues), col = matrixvalues)
x[inx_mat]
#[1] "S" "N" "V" "Z" "X" "K" "I" "F"
```

Comment: When I used this it returned 6 values, instead of 8.  Thoughts?

Comment: @JackKarrde Can you post the code you used to create the index matrix? `seq_along` makes sure row numbers are sequential, therefore all different.

Comment: Weird, once it tried Knitr, it returned 8.  So I guess it worked!  Not sure why when I run the chunk individually it gives only 6...

Comment: I added the exact code I'm working with into the question

Comment: I restarted R and reran all the chunks, and it also returned 8.  Not sure what the issue was, but I think we're good!!! Thanks for the help!